# How to retrieve added edittext value from being added dynamiccally?

Tags: android-studio, android-edittext, onclicklistener

I want to create a simple interface for my apps, which when user click the button, it will add edittext view. Then i want to retrive its value, but i failed to retrieve it. I know the problem is, as the view added, it will only set a new edittext view, a single one. But when user click the button many times, how do i retrieve the edittext value specifically ? And i also need to input it all the edittext in hashmap, to being upload to firebase database.

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code :)

```
GridLayout JobsFieldGrid = findViewById(R.id.GRIDJOBS);

        Button add = findViewById(R.id.AddJobs);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int InitialRowCount = JobsFieldGrid.getRowCount();
                int count = InitialRowCount+1;

                Log.d("row", String.valueOf(InitialRowCount));

                JobsNO = new EditText(TechnicianTaskCard.this);
                JobsNO.setHint("Task "+count+"...");
                JobsNO.setId(count);
                JobsFieldGrid.setRowCount(count);
                JobsFieldGrid.addView(JobsNO);


                /*TODO: RETRIEVE VALUE FROM EACH GENERATED NEW EDITTEXT.*/



            }
        });
```

Comment: How is this question related to Firebase?

Comment: Sorry i will edit the question back, my mistake !